# how do i get aiohttp to output reddit images

Tags: python, reddit, aiohttp, discord.py

```
@commands.command(aliases=['gt'])
async def cat(self, ctx):
    """Outputs image from r/greentext"""

    async with ctx.typing():
        async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as cs:
            async with cs.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/greentext/hot/.json") as r:
                data = await r.json()

                embed = discord.Embed(title = "r/greentext", color = 0xFF0000)
                embed.set_image(url = data["url"])
                embed.set_footer(text = "r/greentext")

                await ctx.send(embed = embed)
```

I know that data["url"]should be correct as that's what the image file is saved as on the website 
as seen in this screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZB3U.jpg
the whole website json is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/greentext/hot/.json 
and if anyone can help me, I can't find an aiohttp help server and the discord.py server doesn't help me at all because they all make you feel stupid for wanting help

Comment: If your question was answered please mark it as [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `url` key at the top level of the reddit response; the images you are referring to are preview images and these are per post so you need to iterate through posts and extract the images:

```py
data = await r.json()
for post in data["data"]["children"]:
    images = post.get("preview", {}).get("images", [])
    if not images:
        print("no preview images for %s..." % post["data"]["title"])
        continue
    image = images[0]  # grab the first image
    embed = discord.Embed(title = "r/greentext", color = 0xFF0000)
    embed.set_image(url = image["source"]["url"])
    embed.set_footer(text = "r/greentext")
```

In order to get more accustomed to responses returned by reddit you can open the response in a [JSON viewer](http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/) and analyze them.